# How to make phone number,links and url all clickable using Html.fromHtml() in TextView

Tags: android, textview, hyperlink

I want to make  links,url,phone number-all clickable using Html.fromHtml() method in a 
   Textview. I am trying this ----

```
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b> Hi this is my text </b> <a href=\"http:\/\/bruynzeelkeukens.nl\/keukenapparatuur\/fornuizen\">fornuizen<\/a>  Call me here: 011 058 299 88   ");
            txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

But this does not make Phone number clickable.  But If I use

```
txt.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
 txt.setLinksClickable(true);
```

then this makes Phone number clickable but does not make anchor tag clickable.
What should I do to make Phoone number,links both  clickable while using Html.fromHtml()?
 Because I have to read Html tags also(like 'bold' tag,'br' tab) And I don't want to use WebView.

Comment: simple display a text and set a onclick listener it is eaier way

Comment: @TheMechanic I don't want to make whole TextView clickable but only PhoneNumber,Links

Comment: k my friend i will post new one for u

Comment: please provide some solution

Comment: @monika If possible use WebView  and pass ur String in webview. It will handle all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occure because of removing spans from your Spanned text. Linkify will remove all html spans before applaying it's own.
 You have to store your html spans and add it back after linkify.

```
 private Spannable linkifyHTML(CharSequence text) {
        Spannable s = new SpannableString(text);

        URLSpan[] old = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), URLSpan.class);
        LinkSpec oldLinks[] = new LinkSpec[old.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < old.length; i++) {
            oldLinks[i] = new LinkSpec(old[i], s.getSpanStart(old[i]), s.getSpanEnd(old[i]));
        }

       Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.ALL);
       for (LinkSpec span : oldLinks) {
           s.setSpan(span.span, span.start, span.end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
       }
       return s;
    }
```

Please see this answer for more info: [How to make all 3 types of links in textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664045/how-to-make-all-3-types-of-links-in-textview/39680193#39680193)\